# Group by a variable and merge row data from another column

Tags: r, merge, grouping, dplyr, rows

I want to group my data by one column and paste the character strings from a different column into a single row. Suppose, for example, I have a `data.frame` `A`:

```
library(dplyr)
A <- data.frame(student = rep(c("John Smith", "Jane Smith"), 3),
                variable1 = rep(c("Var1", "Var1", "Var2"), 2))
    A <- arrange(A, student)

     student variable1
1 Jane Smith      Var1
2 Jane Smith      Var1
3 Jane Smith      Var2
4 John Smith      Var1
5 John Smith      Var2
6 John Smith      Var1
```

But, I need to transform `data.frame` `A` into `data.frame` `B`, grouped by the `student` variable and pasting any variations from `variable1` together:

```
B <- data.frame(student = c("John Smith", "Jane Smith"), 
                variable1 = c(paste("Var1", "Var2", sep = ","),     
                              paste("Var1", "Var2", sep = ",")))

     student variable1
1 John Smith Var1,Var2
2 Jane Smith Var1,Var2
```

I've attempted numerous `group_by` and `mutate` clauses from the `dplyr` package but haven't found success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the aggregate function to do what you are looking for.
Is this what you are trying to do?

```
df=unique(A)
agg=aggregate(df$variable1, list(df$student), paste, collapse=",")

> agg
             Group.1         x
        1 Jane Smith Var1,Var2
        2 John Smith Var1,Var2
```

Comment: Or just `aggregate(variable1 ~ student, unique(A), toString)`

Comment: Great solutions! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the data.table package to do this easily, and quickly if you set student to be your key:

```
library(data.table)
A<-data.table(A)
setkey(A, student)
B<-A[, paste(unique(variable1), collapse=", "),by=student]
```