# Group same value and concat the value in another column in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to sequence a dataset, and I'm a little lost with this.

[image: Input]

I would like to get this result and save it to a csv file:

[image: Output]

Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you can `group_by` your `ID` and then `summarise`. Use `collapse` to indicate what you want to use a separator (in this case, semicolon) for `paste`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(MovieCode = paste(MovieCode, collapse = ";"))
```

Or in base R, use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(MovieCode ~ ID, df, paste, collapse = ";")
```

**Output**

```
   ID   MovieCode
1 ABC A10;A12;A13
2 BDE         A11
3 CDE         A14
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("ABC", "BDE", "ABC", "ABC", "CDE"), MovieCode = c("A10", 
"A11", "A12", "A13", "A14")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: The actual column name Movie Code with space ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with data table:

```
library(data.table)
#create table
ID <- c("ABC","BDE", "ABC","ABC","CDE")
Movie_Code <- c("A10","A11","A12","A13","A14")
df <- data.frame(ID, Movie_Code)
#convert to data table
df<-data.table(df)
setkey(df, ID)
final_tab<-df[, paste(unique(Movie_Code), collapse=", "),by=ID]
#CSV: comma separated values
```

Output:

```
    ID            V1
1: ABC A10, A12, A13
2: BDE           A11
3: CDE           A14
```

From: [Daniel Bachen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536713/13328010)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `base R` solution:

Illustrative data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("ABA", "BCB", "ABA", "BCB", "DCD"),
  v2 = letters[1:5]
)
```

Solution:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  v1_unique = unique(df$v1),
  v2_paste = tapply(df$v2, df$v1, paste0, collapse = ";"), row.names = NULL)
```

Result:

```
df1
  v1_unique v2_paste
1       ABA      a;c
2       BCB      b;d
3       DCD        e
```